# Is an MCMC estimator biased if the confidence interval contains the true parameter value?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo

Let’s assume I am simulating data under a given model, and using MCMC with said data to estimate a (known) model parameter. Let’s assume I do this thousands of times. The results I obtain show that the median of the posterior distribution for this parameter is always smaller than the true value, yet the 95% highest posterior density interval generally contains the true value.

Is the estimator biased? A biased estimator is one whose expected value systematically differs from the true value. If the median of the posterior distribution is the expected value, then it is, as I always obtain smaller values than expected (never larger ones). However, across ~75% of replicates, the true value still falls within the confidence interval of the expected value.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If by bias you mean that $\mathbb E[\hat\mu]\ne\mu$, then $\hat\mu=\text{median}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_T)$ is biased. If by bias you mean that the nominal coverage of the confidence interval is not equal to the actual coverage, then the confidence interval is biased. You must however take into account that the MCMC output emulates a posterior distribution, for which (i) the posterior mean is always biased and (ii) the optimal Bayes estimator is defined in terms of the posterior expected loss, not the bias.